# ResolutionContext creation customization in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

guys.

Maybe someone has the same problem.

I have some cached variables in the `MemoryCache` (standard non-distributed in-memory implementation of `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache`). So, I also have mappings I use for Response/DTO creation. Some of them use variables from `MemoryCache`. But now I must always pass it through

```
opts => 
{
   opts.Items.Add(variableName1, variableValue1);
   opts.Items.Add(variableName2, variableValue2);
   ... 
}
```

or I need to pass each time `MemoryCache` the same way.

Is it possible to set up a global configuration of `ResolutionContext` which allows me to pass all variables from `MemoryCache` I need in the time of the `ResolutionContext` creation? Unfortunately, `BeforeMap` isn't a solution - It has no DI mechanism for `IMemoryCache` resolving. And as I know It can be only one in the mapping structure - Automapper skips all `BeforeMap` after the first one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `ResolutionContext`, you can implement a custom `IMemberValueResolver`, which can get the `IMemoryCache` dependency injected.
By doing so, there's no need to seed the`ResolutionContext` with key/value pairs (being copied from the `IMemoryCache`).

The `FromMemoryCacheResolver` below resolves the value for the requested cache key from the injected `IMemoryCache`.

```
public class FromMemoryCacheResolver<TDestMember>
    : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, TDestMember>
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public FromMemoryCacheResolver(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public TDestMember Resolve(
        object source, object destination, object cacheKey, TDestMember destMember,
        ResolutionContext context
        )
    {
        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out object value)
            && (value != null)
            )
        {
            return (TDestMember)value;
        }

        return default(TDestMember);
    }
}
```

---

**Example**

```
public class Source
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Target
{
    public decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }

    public string StringValue { get; set; } 
}
```

Given the above `Source` and `Target` classes,  you can define an `AutoMapper` mapping that sets a target property to the value bound to a fixed cache key (see `DecimalValue` rule) or a dynamic cache key (including a property value of the source object, see `StringValue` rule).

```
CreateMap<Source, Target>()
    .ForMember(
        o => o.DecimalValue,
        opt => opt.MapFrom<FromMemoryCacheResolver<decimal>, object>(
            _ => "constant-cache-key"
    ))
    .ForMember(
        o => o.StringValue,
        opt => opt.MapFrom<FromMemoryCacheResolver<string>, object>(
            src => $"dynamic-cache-key-{src.Id}"
    ));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could override the way AutoMapper is registered in your dependency injection container and perform an action just before it is resolved. Assuming you use standard Microsoft's DI:

```cs
// Your code adding AutoMapper
services.AddAutoMapper(assembliesOrMarkerTypes);

// Remove just the IMapper
services.RemoveAll(typeof(IMapper));

// Add it again, but with filling the Items dictionary from cache
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(
    typeof(IMapper),
    sp =>
    {
        var memoryCache = sp.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();

        var valueFromCache = memoryCache.Get<string>("foo");

        var mapper = new Mapper(sp.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationProvider>(), sp.GetService);

        // Does not work!
        // mapper.DefaultContext.Items.Add("foo", valueFromCache);

        // Use Items from Options:
        mapper.DefaultContext.Options.Items.Add("foo", valueFromCache);

        return mapper;
    },
    ServiceLifetime.Transient)); // <== Default AutoMapper lifetime
```

There are two downsizes to this:

#### 1) Access `Items` from resolution context's options, not directly

There is a check made when accessing `Items` in resolution context preventing from accessing them in a default context, which is a source for creating other contexts used in mapping. Luckily, there is no such check when accessing `Items` from options:

```cs
var items = resolutionContext.Options.Items;
```

So don't do that:

```cs
var items = resolutionContext.Items;
```

#### 2) Don't use Map() with `Action<IMappingOperationOptions>`

You can't use any `Map()` method accepting `Action<IMappingOperationOptions>` because it will effectively overwrite content of `Items` dictionary created when initializing the mapper with entries from the mapping operation options, even if none were set. So, you can't do this:

```cs
var result = mapper.Map(source, destination, opts => otps.Items["bar"] = "bar");
```

#### Final note

Overall it's a bit of a hack and surely this code wouldn't win the beauty contest, so consider encapsulating it in some decent extension method for `IServiceCollection`.